# Werewolf Puzzle

Tags: logic, puzzle, boolean-algebra

A certain village has 3 inhabitants, each either human or werewolf. Humans always tell the truth and werewolves always lie. They each make a statement:

**Advik** says, "At least one of us is a werewolf."
**Bardia** says, "At least one of us is a human."
**Cherry** says, "Exactly two of us are werewolves."

What must be true?

The discussion declares **Advik** as **Human** like this:

Suppose **Advik** is a werewolf. Then his claim that there is at least one werewolf would be true, but werewolves can't tell the truth. **So he must be a human instead**.

It supposes that Advik is a Werewolf but why is it not supposing it a Human?
Secondly Advik doesn't say that he is a werewolf so even if we suppose him a Werewolf, he being the liar does make him a human.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Either Advik is a werewolf or a human. That much is true. If he's a human, he's not a werewolf. If he's a werewolf, he's not a human. So it suffices to check each possibility to then conclude he's not a werewolf, and therefore a human.

Comment: The argument shows that Advik cannot be a werewolf, so he must be human. *Your sentence "Secondly ... a human"  makes no sense to me.*

Comment: The strategy here is to show that any system with A=W is inconsistent, so if there is a consistent answer we must have A=H. I imagine that the proof goes on with A=H (and assuming there is a consistent answer) to note that B makes a true statement. Note that A's first statement is context dependent and "us" refers to the current group. It doesn't have a truth value without a context.

Comment: "I'm a werewolf... awoooo."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They can't all be werewolves, because then Advik would be telling the truth, and werewolves don't tell the truth.

They can't all be humans, because then Advik would be lying, and humans don't lie.

So there is at least one werewolf and at least one human.

Therefore Advik is telling the truth, so he must be a human. Similarly, Bardia is telling the truth, so he must also be a human.

So Advik and Bardia are humans. That means Cherry is lying, hence is a werewolf.

---

Note: the above assumes that an individual cannot be both a human and a werewolf!

Comment: Now I got it why its a contradiction. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Each of the three inhabitants is *either* a human *or* a werewolf. The given line of reasoning shows that Advik being a werewolf is a *contradiction*: that would make his statement true but a werewolf cannot utter truth. So Advik, by elimination, must be human; there is therefore no need to assume Advik is a human, we derive it.

Comment: @Bungo I was being a bit silly there.

Comment: Understood, it's a silly puzzle anyway. :-D

Comment: @ParclyTaxel If its a contradiction then that would mean that we are pre supposing his statement as being true. So how do we know that all three can't be humans?

Comment: @ShiranAbbasi They can't all be humans, because if that were the case, Advik would be lying when he says there is at least one werewolf. And humans don't lie.

Comment: @ShiranAbbasi Do you understand how contradiction works?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Yes I got it. I was a little confused. Contradiction means considering a statement true makes it false.